# OkHttp networkInterceptors does not catch client connect timeouts?

Tags: java, networking, retrofit, interceptor, okhttp

I've been testing the out Application vs Network Interceptors for OkHttp clients. I created an simple interceptor that simply logs latency and errors if errors occur.

I found that if I purposely set:

```
client.setConnectTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Only Application Interceptors will intercept and chain the request. If I add the interceptor as a Network Interceptor, my intercept() method is never hit on the connect timeout.

Why is this the case?

The distinction made on the doc here https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors is not super obvious to me.

I'm adding the interceptor by calling:

```
client.interceptors().addAll(interceptors);
```

or:

```
client.networkInterceptors().addAll(interceptors);
```

Answer (score 0):

A timeout of `0` means no timeout at all: the call will be allowed to run indefinitely.

Note that interceptors typically return before the response body has been streamed. If your timeout occurs while reading the response body a network interceptor won't observe it.

Finally the connection is established after all application interceptors but before any network interceptors. If the timeout occurs on connect the network interceptors won't be executed.